# Mongodb $lookup does not return values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongodb with node (mongoose). I have several queries like the one below.

```
db.Private.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'recipients',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'recipientObj',
        },
    },
])
```

The one above works fine. However the query down below doesn't.

```
db.Global.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'from',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'fromObj'
        }
    }
])
```

Although I get the results it does not give the aggregation.

sample data looks like this:

user-> `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f9c31236921c3001866d811"), "number" : "22", "username" : "Abraham", "name" : "Abraham Kiprop Lagat" }`

Global-> `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f9ff4d27f166700117f40d4"), "from" : "5f9c31236921c3001866d811", "body" : "this is global from 22", "date" : "1604318418952", "__v" : 0 }`

What could be the issue?

Comment: looks like the `from` in the `global` collection is saved as `string` and not `ObjectId` making the lookup exact match to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Found a mismatch on the data types, seems the ObjectId was being saved as a string. Had to convert it into an ObjectId using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(jwtUser.id)` . Works perfectly.